# How to cache a view in urls.py when it is direct to template

Tags: django, caching

I would like to `cache` a template and I know that it possible to do this in the `url`. However, the specific template I would like to cache is also delviered with a  direct to template:

```
(r'^menu/$', direct_to_template, { 'template': 'corp_menu.html' }),
```

Does anyone know how to convert my `url` to `cache` this using the django documentation:

The `django` documentation shows

```
urlpatterns = ('',
(r'^foo/(\d{1,2})/$', cache_page(60 * 15)(my_view)),
)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(r'^menu/$', cache_page(60 * 15)(direct_to_template), { 'template': 'corp_menu.html' }),
```

should work.